# Firebase matches() doesn't work with regex

Tags: regex, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to implement this regex https://regex101.com/r/9m7vMC/1/ (it checks coordinate latitude) in my firebase validation rule. This is my code:

```
"coordinate": {
    "latitude": {
        ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().matches(/^(\\+|-)?(?:90(?:(?:\\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-8][0-9])(?:(?:\\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$/)"
    }
}
```

I've escaped `+` and `.`, hence there are double backslashes `\\+` and `\\.`

But this code doesn't work. When I try to write a correct latitude I got an error `FIREBASE WARNING: update at / failed: permission_denied`

Comment: Do you have write access?

Comment: yes, when I remove validation for latitude everything works well.

Comment: In a regular expression literal - not a string literal - you only need a single backslash to escape the `+`. Your `\\+` is attempting to match one or more backslashes.

Comment: But then during save (publish) I get an error:
`Error saving rules - Line 18: Invalid escape: '\+'`

Comment: My mistake. You are right. It's JSON, so the backslashes are escaped.

Comment: Actually, I think I've had a similar problem in the past. Try it without the non-capturing groups: `/^(\\+|-)?(90((\\.0{1,6})?)|([0-9]|[1-8][0-9])((\\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$/`

Comment: It works now, thanks @cartant

Comment: I've added an answer, as it seems pretty likely that others might find this information useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the non-capturing groups (`?:`) that you have in the regular expression that are the problem.

I remember having a similar issue with a regular expression that I was using to validate ISO 8601 times in a Firebase database. Changing the non-capturing groups to capturing groups solved the problem for me.

To replace the non-capturing groups with capturing groups, just remove the uses of `?:` from your regular expression:

```
"coordinate": {
  "latitude": {
    ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().matches(/^(\\+|-)?(90((\\.0{1,6})?)|([0-9]|[1-8][0-9])((\\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$/)"
  }
}
```